# Distributed file system vs mounting a drive over the network.

Tags: filesystems, distributed

I would like to ask you, what are the pros/cons of having a distributed file system off the shelf (like HadoopFS) over just mounting a drive over the network on linux? As I understand we will achieve the same with these two approaches: the same data will be available on many remote locations.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Distributed filesystems provide many benefits like automatic backup or distributions on some rules (you can, say, add many new elements to your storage and that operation will be transparent for your applications using the storage).

Mounting drives can become a pain one day, when one of your elements in the network gets off on some reason, while your applications rely on it.